# TikZ current page node is in unexpected place

Tags: tikz-pgf

Edit: there was a mistake in my original question. The wrong output occurs with "latex", but not with "pdflatex". I'll rephrase the question to be more accurate and succinct.

I am trying to position some object at an absolute position on the page, following the examples from Section 17.13.2 of the TikZ manual ("Referencing the Current Page Node - Absolute Positioning"). I am looking at version 3.0.1a of the manual. The following example is directly from the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

This example adds a circle in the middle of the page.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25]
  (current page.center) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this with "pdflatex bug.tex" (twice), the output is as expected:

[image: output from pdflatex]

When I compile the same file with "latex bug.tex" (twice), and the convert the DVI file to PDF with "dvips bug.dvi -o" and "pdf2ps bug.ps", the output is wrong. The circle is not centered.

[image: output from latex]

Notice that only the circle has moved, not the rest of the page. So the problem is not with dvips or pdf2ps. The mistake is already present in the DVI file. Moreover, there is a difference in the file bug.aux. When compiling with pdflatex, the file contains

```
\relax 
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{9782558}{42447667}
```

When compiling with latex, the file contains

```
\relax 
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{9782558}{45729504}
```

What goes wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How often did you compile? You need to compile two or three times (I forgot) to get the node at the right place.

Comment: example from manual works. node is correctly positioned after two compilation!

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I followed your steps and cannot reproduce the issue on my up-to-date TeXLive 2018 distribution. Regardless of whether I compile with latex or pdflatex, I always get `\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{9782558}{42447667}` in my aux file. Zarko's answer is on pgfplictures, and does not apply on this, I think.

Answer (score 1):

from pgf & tikz manual (3.0.1a) follows:

> 101.3.2 Referencing Anchors of Nodes in Different Pictures
>
> As a picture is typeset, pgf keeps track of the positions of all nodes
>   inside the picture. What pgf does not remember is the position of the
>   picture itself on the page. Thus, if you define a node in one picture
>   and then try to reference this node while another picture is typeset,
>   pgf will only know the position of the nodes that you try to typeset
>   inside the original picture, but it will not know where this picture
>   lies. What is missing is the relative positioning of the two pictures.
>   To overcome this problem, you need to tell pgf that it should remember
>   the position of pictures on a page. If these positions are remembered,
>   then pgf can compute the offset between the pictures and make nodes in
>   different pictures accessible. Determining the positions of pictures
>   on the page is, alas, not-so-easy. Because of this, pgf does not do so
>   automatically. Rather, you have to proceed as follows:
>
> 1. You have to use a backend driver that supports position tracking. pdfTEX is one such driver, **dvips currently is not**.
> 2. You have to say \pgfrememberpicturepositiononpagetrue somewhere before or inside every picture ...

conclusion, so far your way of copmpilation will not give desired result! you need to use pdfLaTeX or XeLatEX or LuaLaTeX ...

Comment: You are reading the section on pgfpictures. I guess it would be more appropriate to check if you get different `\pgfsyspdfmark` when you compile with latex vs. pdflatex. I don't.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue. On my TeXLive 2018 distribution, regardless of whether I compile with `latex` or `pdflatex`, I always get an identical entry in the `aux` file

```
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{9782558}{42447667}
```

The results are indistinguishable.

This raises the question which LaTeX distribution you are using.

I also cannot follow Zarko's discussion, which in my opinion mixes two things: `pgfpictures` and `tikzpictures`. He is quoting from `quoting from section 101, which starts with

> This section describes the shapes module.
>   \usepgfmodule{shapes}.

It is, of course, not excluded that there are issues with the conversion chain `tex -> dvi -> ps -> pdf` but at least on my machine I cannot reproduce your issues.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I'll answer my own question.

I confirm that the described behavior does not happen with TeXLive 2018; this explains why marmot could not reproduce it. I had been using TeXLive 2017. So it seems that this was indeed a bug and has been fixed.

The other piece of information is that in TeXLive 2017, the bug can be circumvented by putting

```
 \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
```

before any code that accesses the "current page" node (and after any code that updates \paperheight, such as when using the geometry package). Maybe this information will be useful to people still using TeXLive 2017 (which ships with the current version of Ubuntu, for example).